# Utilizar node.js ou PHP com WebSockets?

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

Uso WebSockets para meu projeto, no final ficou um extenso projeto com milhares de linhas de código em PHP.

Assim que eu acabei escrever tudo e "terminar" me dizem que executar WebSockets com PHP é inviável para larga escala de usuários por ele ser síncrono e executa tudo novamente para cada requisição.

Me recomendaram node.js como alternativa devido ao baixo *overhead* e ser assíncrono.

Mas ao mesmo tempo eu penso que se a arquitetura de execução dentro do servidor estiver adequada tentando ao máximo não ter muitos gastos o uso de uma linguagem ou outra para o mesmo fim acaba ficando elas por elas.

Minhas dúvidas são especificadamente:

- Existe alguma proporção em relação a node.js e PHP que me demonstre o
  quantos % ele seria mais eficiente, ou algo do gênero?
- Não existe uma alternativa para que eu não precise sair do PHP? Mesmo que eu mude as estruturas de meu projeto

É frustrante minha situação, e como projetos de hoje em dia podem encher-se de usuários ou não eu fico meio sem saber pra onde correr.

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta, mas considere o seguinte: se o número de usuários do seu projeto crescer além da conta, ao menos você terá recursos para refazer o que tiver que refazer (e com certeza vão aparecer muitas coisas não previstas à medida que ele crescer em escala). Não otimize prematuramente, muito menos com base em "a tecnologia X não serve pra fazer Y", às vezes pode até ser verdade, mas com frequência não é (sem querer admitir que sua implementação foi ruim, os desenvolvedores culpam a plataforma).

Comment: Em vez disso, procure saber *o que* WebSockets demandam e *em que sentido* PHP não parece uma boa escolha para atender essa demanda, e se isso é culpa da linguagem, da implementação, do *webserver* que roda por trás... E veja se não dá pra contornar isso, sem ter que mudar radicalmente sua arquitetura (ou talvez ao aprender mais você até descubra que tem que mudar a arquitetura, mas sem mudar a linguagem). Infelizmente eu não conheço nada de WebSockets (até estou interessado em ver o que respondem aqui), senão poderia tentar dar uns ponteiros, mas realmente estou no escuro...

Comment: @mgibsonbr levei em conta suas informações, editei a pergunta adicionando mais coisas e espero novidades enquanto sigo com a pesquisa.. Obrigada!

Comment: Quem disse que [PHP só pode ser sincrono](http://reactphp.org/) ?

Comment: @gmsantos como eu disse ainda estou pesquisando, e por acaso conheci esse reactphp a alguns minutos.. edições são aceitas..

Comment: Me deparei com um tal de ratchet que usa react para ser websocket assíncrono com PHP.. irei ler mais..

Comment: @Elaine não vejo como edição a pergunta, mas sim a formulação de uma resposta :)
Infelizmente estou sem tempo pra escrever o pouco que conheço.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP v NODE.js](https://medium.com/node-js-em-portugues/php-vs-node-js-entendendo-o-modelo-de-execucao-bf2579064263#.nzqj1kx5c) - A questão de que o PHP carrega tudo novamente varia de um fator, se o PHP roda sobre o Apache como um processo, criando a cada requisição uma nova instância, ou se o mesmo roda sobre o FastCGI, o qual podemos limitar o numero de threads associdas ao processo único, desta forma a execução sendo assincrona, a execução deste modo geralmente é aplicado no Lighttpd e o Nginx, embora possa ser aplicado no Apache também.

Utilizando-se do FastCGI/PHP obterá basicamente o mesmo resultado, embora o Node.js seja mais facil para criação de aplicações que utilizem Websocket. Como já possui a aplicação feita, recomendo manter o PHP e utilizar o FastCGI.