# Melhoria em aplicação de Chat

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho

Estou desenvolvendo um chat para o meu site onde um usuário manda um convite para o outro usuário, caso o mesmo aceite será aberto e o sistema ficará verificando novas mensagens.

Para o sistema fazer essa verificação utilizo um `while`, e enquanto não retorna nenhum resultado, eu pego o ultimo `id` da memsagem que recebi, crio uma `query` para trazer resultados maiores que aquele `id` fornecido. Após executar uma repetição e não retornar nada dou um `sleep` de 1 segundo no [php](/questions/tagged/php) para não sobrecarregar.

Gostaria de saber se alguém conseguiu construir um *chat* com um sistema diferente e como fez? Existe alguma técnica que seja de mais performática do que o *long-polling*?

Comment: websocket? Relacionado: [Utilizar node.js ou PHP com WebSockets?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90892/91)

Comment: Vou verificar :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa prática que você está aplicando torna a aplicação inutilizável, pois vai ficar segurando o [php](/questions/tagged/php) até ter uma mensagem, possibilitando uma grande chance de dar *timeout*.

A melhor jogada nesse caso seria usando *websockets*.
Segue um exemplo:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Comment: Sim, mas tem um tempo limite de 10 segs, enquanto for menor que esse tempo ele vai ficar dando o while, caso não tenha nenhum resultando até 10 segs, eu finalizo o while e retorno 0 para  javascript. E depois o javascript manda mais um AJAXe tudo se inicia denovo.

Comment: Nesse caso utilizar websocket pode ser meio perigoso, pois se o navegador do usuário não der suporte ao HTML5 o sistema fica inutilizável.

Comment: Estava analisando ele é muito bom, mas o único problema são os navegadores sem suporte ao HTML5, fora isso seria perfeito. Vou dar mais uma estudada nisso, pois não entendi muito o processo. Nunca tinha ouvindo falar desse processo.